# Need all the ahadith that promise the Jannah if anyone does the specific worship mentioned in the hadith

Tags: hadith, muslim-practices, ibadah

I need all the ahadith that state about the most rewarding deeds or promised the Jannah if anyone does consistently, for example (I know some of this kind of ahadith):-

**`The Excellence of Performing two Rak'ah of Voluntary Prayer after Ablution:`**

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger
> of Allah (PBUH) said to Bilal (May Allah be pleased with him) "Tell me
> about the most hopeful act (i.e., one which you deem the most
> rewarding with Allah) you have done since your acceptance of Islam
> because I heard the sound of the steps of your shoes in front of me in
> Jannah.'' Bilal said: "I do not consider any act more hopeful than
> that whenever I make Wudu' (or took a bath) in an hour of night or
> day, I would immediately perform Salat (prayer) for as long as was
> destined for me to perform.'' [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

**`Al-Sunan Al-Rawatib`**

> Anbasah ibn Abi Sufyan quoted Umm Habibah as saying "Allah’s Messenger
> (may peace and blessings be upon him) said:
>
> "A house will be built in Heaven for one who prays 12 Rak'at in a day
> and evening as follows: 4 Rak'at before and 2 after the Zhuhr Prayer,
> 2 after the Maghrib Prayer, 2 after the ‘Isha Prayer and 2 before the
> Fajr Prayer." (Narrated by at-Tirmidhi under No. 380. He said: The
> Hadith narrated by Anbasah quoting Umm Habibah in this chapter is a
> hassan and sahih hadith. It is under No. 6362 in Sahih al-Jami’.

**`Beautiful names & attributes of Allah`**

> Al-Bukhaari (2736) and Muslim (2677) narrated from Abu Hurayrah that
> the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah
> has ninety-nine names. Whoever memorizes them will enter Paradise.”

These ahadith mentioned the Jannah for those who performs those specific worship. And I believe there’s so many other ahadith that also state the same way, so I'm asking for those ahadith that promised or gave the admission of Jannah.